# Error: objects 'ripras', 'as.ppp', 'delaunay' are not exported by 'namespace:spatstat'

Tags: delaunay, spatstat

I got following error whie executing the code.

Code:install.packages("ithir", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")

Error:

```
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/cloud-user/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
installing the source package ‘ithir’

trying URL 'http://R-Forge.R-project.org/src/contrib/ithir_1.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 4534681 bytes (4.3 MB)
downloaded 4.3 MB

* installing *source* package 'ithir' ...
** using staged installation
** R
** data
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error: objects 'ripras', 'as.ppp', 'delaunay' are not exported by 'namespace:spatstat'
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'ithir'
* removing 'C:/Users/cloud-user/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2/ithir'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ithir’ had non-zero exit status
```

I was trying to install a package ithir.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says in the first line that you will need to install `Rtools` before you can build packages. Visit CRAN.r-project.org for information about installing `Rtools`.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=2000 the package you are trying to install was last updated in 2016. Since then `spatstat` was split into many smaller packages due to requirements from the package repository CRAN. Thus `ithir` as found on that site tries to call functions in `spatstat` which are now in e.g. `spatstat.geom`. If you want to use such an old package you also need old versions of other packages. You can find old versions of spatstat that may work with this package at: https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/spatstat/

**Edit:** I just noticed that `ithir` seems to be moved to bitbucket and no longer depends on `spatstat`. You should probably install it from here: https://bitbucket.org/brendo1001/ithir/